# FixedResolutionViewport change color of black border

Tags: flutter, flame

In the documentation of `FixedResolutionViewport` of Flame, it says that the color of the black border around the viewport (when it doesn't fit into the screen) is configurable (defaulted to black). I couldn't find a way to configure this color. Is there an example where this is being done?

From the documentation:

> So for example, if the viewport happens to be the same ratio of the screen, it will resize to fit 100%. But if they are different ratios, it will resize the most it can and then will add black (color is configurable) borders.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a Look at this :

[**Link:** https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_screenutil)

```
dependencies:
  flutter_screenutil: ^5.1.1
```

---

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //Set the fit size (Find your UI design, look at the dimensions of the device screen and fill it in,unit in dp)
    return ScreenUtilInit(
      designSize: Size(360, 690),
      minTextAdapt: true,
      splitScreenMode: true,
      builder: () =>
          MaterialApp(
            //... other code
            builder: (context, widget) {
              //add this line
              ScreenUtil.setContext(context);
              return MediaQuery(
                //Setting font does not change with system font size
                data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(textScaleFactor: 1.0),
                child: widget,
              );
            },
            theme: ThemeData(
              textTheme: TextTheme(
                //To support the following, you need to use the first initialization method
                  button: TextStyle(fontSize: 45.sp)
              ),
            ),
          ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you probably missed that the question was about Flame's `FixedResolutionViewport`?